# Android MediaPlayer to show a progressdialog until the song is buffered

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**What i have:** code that plays mp3 song from server. It is working correctly

**What i am trying to do:**

1. place a progress dialog until onPrepared() event is reached which is
   not happening
2. I tried using progress dialog as we do in async task which is not
   showing up.
3. Is there any other correct way to do this

### ***This i am trying to do because UI hangs in case of low net connectivity, there is no problem in case of good connectivity***

---

```
<------- Blah blah code---------->
..
..
..
play(<mp3url>);

public void play(String url) {
        try {
            //mediaPlayer.stop();

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            if(pd.isShowing() && pd!=null){
                pd.dismiss();
                pd=null;
            }
            pd = new ProgressDialog(ActAtomicGodDetailTunesCategorySongs.this);
            pd.setMessage("loading...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

            //mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mediaPlayer.start();
        //mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        //seekBarProgress.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);

    } 


@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        seekBarProgress.setMax(duration);
        if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBarProgress.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
    }
..
..
..
<------- Blah blah code---------->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text view(Text: Buffering) instead of using Progress Dialog.

```
public void playmusic(){
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            text_buffer= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_buffer);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(store);
            text_buffer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
             //very important. you should do this prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    text_buffer.setVisibility(View.GONE);//or you can use View.INVISIBLE
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playState=true;     // This is boolean to check whether music plays or not
                }
            });
```